# how to add , edit and delete comma separated value of database .?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have created one table called role and the fields are like (roleid,role,prohibitedprocess,prohibitedports) here roleid is unique. and i have a comma separated value for "prohibitedprocess" field .(ex: prohibitedprocess---> skype,teamviwer,notepad).

the problem is how to add and edit and  delete that comma separated value of prohibitedprocess .is it possible ?

i have fetch the code form the data base .code is

```
      <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT roleid, prohibitedprocess, prohibitedports FROM role WHERE role='Basic'";
                $option='';
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $pro_proc = $row['prohibitedprocess'];
                    $lst = explode(",",$pro_proc);
                                        //Print in Option Box
                    foreach($lst as $exp)
                    {?> 
                        <tr>            
                        <td><?php echo $exp;?></td>
                        <td><a href="edit_form.php?id=$row[roleid]">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="del_form.php?id=$row[roleid]">Delete</a></td></tr>
            <?php   
                    }
                }                       
                ?>
```

[image: Design]

How to do this please help me

Comment: Storing comma seperated values in a relation database breaks a lot of rules. It makes the data unstructured and as you found out hard to work with. If you need to store data lile this look at a NoSQL alternative. Otherwise redesign your data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the whole string . .

I mean just using str_replace function

e.g

```
$string = "skype,teamviwer,notepad";

$old_value = "skype";

$new_value = "facebook";

$new_string = str_replace($old_value,$new_value,$string);
```

Then simply update this new string into database table. .

Comment: Simply add this code for delete. . 

$new_string = str_replace($old_value,"",$string);

Comment: And for add new one

$string = "skype,teamviwer,notepad";

$new_value = "anil";

$new_string=$string.",".$new_value;

Comment: while deleting what is the $new_string . i just want delete  the old string

Comment: @Nayana    Its the final string you need to update in all the operations you need to execute update operation . . so dont use delete or insert operation. . .

Comment: while deleting one comma is left in database. how to clear that ?

Comment: attach comma(,) with your old value
$old_value  = $old_value.",";

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to retrieve all of 'keywords' in an input element and edit them like a sentence. However, for what you want to do, you may wanna add a new table called prohibitedprocess and use roleid as a foreign key. Then retrieve from that table according the roleid.
eg: `SELECT item FROM prohibitedprocess p, role r WHERE p.roleid = r.roleid`

Comment: i am not getting you how to do  :(

Comment: There are 2 solutions. Keep them all in one table or create a separated table for prohibitedprocess with the fields **id, roleid, keyword** then when you insert a new roled, you tale the roleid and insert all the prohibited processes in the table prohibitedprocess using roleid as the foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to make another table for that relation, then you could edit it normally. Otherwise you can take your comma separated list and do something in javascript.

```
var commaSeparatedList = <?php echo $commaSeparatedList;?>
var realData = commaSeparatedList.split(',');
// when the user adds something you can add to the array or delete 
// from the array
var newCommaList = readData.join([separator = ',']);
// some kind of get/post request that sends the new comma list

<?php
    $newList = GET_REQUEST_PARAMS["newCommaList"];
    // sql update query that updates the comma list
?>
```

I haven't used php in a while so I know GET_REQUEST_PARAMS isn't a thing but i'm sure you know how to get the parameters.

Or without javascript you can use a form that posts back all the names of prohibited things

```
<?php 
    $newList = ""
    //foreach through the get params which contain the names
    foreach()
    {
        $newList += getParam + ",";
    }
    // some code to remove that last comma
    // sql update 
?>
```